# coffee concentrate and water separated after 2 hours. How/why?

Tags: water, separation-techniques

I'm asking because this makes no sense to me and making sure I'm not stupid.

I brewed 10 gallons of cold brew concentrate(TDS 12.2) and mixed it with 10 gallons of water.

I moved 10 gallons of the mixture into kegs and they ended up at TDS 6.4. Two hours later I filled the rest of the kegs. One keg was at TDS 4.8 while the rest were at TDS 0.4.

Will coffee and water separate? I've never seen this happen before and previous kegs have never tasted differently until just now.

Comment: Then you most probably didn't mix properly.

Comment: I guess my main question is: how are the water and coffee concentrate not homogenous? and how would I ensure proper mixing?

Again, we've never seen this happen before.